# How to replace whole response body with gsub in lua?

Tags: regex, lua, gsub

I tried to replace my whole response body with gsub and regex in lua, my code look like this

```
    ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. ngx.arg[1]
    if ngx.arg[2] then
        ngx.arg[1] = ngx.ctx.buffered:gsub(".*", "TESTING")
    else
        ngx.arg[1] = ''
    end
```

but why my response is "TESTINGTESTING", when it should be only "TESTING"

Comment: how do you get that output? TESTINGTESTING should not be possible as `.*` matches any set of characters. even the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ngx.arg[1] = ngx.ctx.buffered:gsub(".*", "TESTING")`

with `ngx.arg[1] = "TESTING"`

There is no point in using gsub with `".*"`.